# Jax-rx Starter Maven project showing error HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

I have a new Java Jax-rs starter maven project, from which I am able to create a war file. When I am tried to start it with the tomcat server, its showing HTTP Status 404 – Not Found for all the routes. Anyone who has faced this problem please help me,

Steps I followed inside my Eclipse ID
1.Create a new Project
2.Select Other
3. Select a wizard, Maven -> Maven Project
4. Use default work location, press next
5. Archetype I have selected **jersey-quickstart-webapp**

then the project created.
After I have configured my tomcat server, and I am able to run the app on that tomcat server, but for all the routes even default routes it is showing
**404 page not found**

adding my files

> MyResource.java

```
package com.testing.restapi;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "chal gaya madarchod";
    }
}
```

> pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testing.restapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>restapi</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restapi</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>restapi</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.28</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

> index.js

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
    <p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
    <p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!
</body>
</html>
```

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.testing.restapi</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How do you deploy the application to the server? Maybe the application is not deployed correctly.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha i had two servers running, one tomcat from Homebrew and another was from tomcat directory. Thanks for giving the time on my silly mistake.

Comment: Your question is getting viral, about that string return. I get the frustration